# Custom Iterator not working for the Array Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6];
array[Symbol.iterator] = (function() {
  var current = 0;
  console.log('executed')
  var iterator = {
    next: function() {
      var iteratorObject = {
        done: "undefined",
        value: false
      };
      //returns the next item in the sequence
      if (current != this.length) {

        iteratorObject.done = this[current];
        current++;

        //return false
        return iteratorObject;
      } else if (current === this.length) {
        //finished
        //return true
        iteratorObject.done = "undefined";
        iteratorObject.value = true;
        return iteratorObject;


      } else {
        console.log('something broke!')
      }

    }
  }
  return iterator;
})();
```

In the code above, I am writing a custom iterator for the array object I created. However, it keeps using the built in Symbol.iterator for the array, why is this the case?

Here is the output when I try to run my custom iterator
[image]

As you can tell its running the built in iterator not the custom one that I made?

Comment: how are you trying to "use" this iterator

Comment: Try removing this `2` number after first line end.

Comment: @Azhy ya idk why that was there but it makes no difference

Comment: here's the thing ... `for (i of array);` throws an error `Uncaught TypeError: array is not iterable` - because your code is wrong - you say *As you can tell its running the built in iterator not the custom one that I made?*, but that's where you are wrong .... the console output you've shown actually shows that the iterator is **your code** - the "default" iterator would output `ƒ values() { [native code] }`

Comment: perhaps the issue is that you are using `for...in` and think that is using your code - it doesn't. *The `for...in` statement iterates over all non-Symbol, enumerable properties of an object.* where as *The `for...of` statement creates a loop iterating over iterable objects* - which is why I asked 20 minutes ago *how* are you using this - which you seemed to have ignored

Comment: you also seem to have swapped the meaning of done and value in your code anyway

Comment: and finally, `array[Symbol.iterator]` needs to be a **function**, but because of `})();` you've made it an object

Answer (score 2):

Here is where you went wrong

1. You think you haven't overwritten `array.[Symbol.iterator]` - your `console.log` proves you that you actually have
2. `for(i of array)` throws an error `Uncaught TypeError: array is not iterable` because your code is wrong
3. you also have swapped the meaning of `done` and `value` in what `next()` returns
4. when done, `value` should be the value `undefined` not the string `"undefined"`
5. `array[Symbol.iterator]` needs to be a function - but you've set it to an `Object` - because of the final `()`

Fixing all the issues, you get

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6];
array[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
    let current = 0;
    return {
        next: () => {
            if (current != this.length) {
                return { value: this[current++], done:false };
            } else if (current === this.length) {
                return {value:undefined, done:true};
            } else {
                console.log('something broke!')
            }

        }
    };
};
for(let i of array) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: the for loop is just "test" code to show it works - nothing to do with actual use case :p but have done so for completeness

Comment: no, you're right, answers should use "correct" code principals :p